# How do I query and display child and grandchild data in EF 6 and MVC 5?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an app using EF 6 and MVC 5 that works fine for inputting data, but now when I try to display some of it I'm having troubles.  The basic layout of my entities can be seen in the following diagram:

[image: entity layout]

The first part where I'm having trouble is in querying and filtering the data.  I would like to return a list of premises and related data where a survey and signoff exist, but an approval does not.  In straight SQL, the query that works now is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Premises p LEFT OUTER JOIN Approvals a ON a.Id = p.Id
JOIN Surveys s ON s.PremiseId = p.Id
JOIN SignOffs so ON so.Id = s.Id
WHERE a.ApprovedBy IS NULL
```

The code that I started with is like this:

```cs
var premises = Premises.Include(p => p.Approval)
    .Include(p => p.Surveys)
    .Include(p => p.Surveys.Select(s => s.SignOff));
```

This *appears** to return all records including the child data, but when I try to filter it so I get only records that have a signoff record but do not have an approval, it doesn't work.

```cs
var premises = Premises.Include(p => p.Approval).Where(p => p.Approval.ApprovedBy == null)
    .Include(p => p.Surveys)
    .Include(p => p.Surveys.Select(s => s.SignOff).Where(s => s.Signature != null));
```

If I use this code, I get this error:

**The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path**

I've changed this query around a lot to try different things, so I'm not sure what all I have done, but I think the first `Where` statement might work by itself, but the second one definetly causes the error.
How do I need to structure my query to get it to return the requested data properly filtered?

Also, I put an asterisk above on stating that the query *appears* to return all the data and child data because I can't actually test it.  When I'm trying to write my Razor CSHTML page for this, it's not giving me intellisense for the child and grandchild data, and if I enter what I think it should be I get errors.  How do I need to reference this data on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Include()` like this, it is only good for specifying to load a navigation property, not to specify to load an entity when a navigation property is something (not null, in your case).

To do the filtering, I suggest something like this:

```
var premises = Premises.Include(p => p.Approval).Include(p => p.Surveys).Include(p => p.Surveys.Select(s => s.SignOff))
               .Where(p=>p.Approval.ApprovedBy!=null && p.Surveys.Any(s=>s.SignOff.Signature!=null));
```

So basically, the includes and the filtering have nothing to do with each other. With the includes, you only specify what to load, you can still use the filter on the original entity set.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing what the `Include` LINQ method does. It only tells EF to eagerly load that relationship, which is actually unnecessary if your query itself utilizes that relationship; EF will include the relationship by default in that case.

What it doesn't do is allow you filter those relationships. For example, in this portion of your code:

```
.Include(p => p.Surveys.Select(s => s.SignOff).Where(s => s.Signature != null));
```

The where clause is applied to `Premises`, *not* `SignOff` as you seem to think. In other words, `Where` filters the main table being queried, not the table you're including.

There's two paths forward here. You can simply filter `Premises` by the important parts, i.e.:

```
var premises = Premises.Where(p => p.Approval.ApprovedBy == null && p => p.Surveys.Any(s => s.SignOff.Signature != null));
```

That will return only premises where these conditions are true, but the included `Surveys` collection will contain *all* surveys related to each premise, not just the ones with null signoff signatures.

If you need to filter the related items as well, then you must explicitly load them:

```
foreach (premise in premises)
{
    context.Entry(premise) 
        .Collection(p => p.Surveys) 
        .Query() 
        .Where(s => s.SignOff.Signature != null) 
        .Load();
}
```

Two things of note:

1. Because of the nature of how this query must be applied, there's no way to do it once for all premises. You'll have to iterate over the premises and explicitly load the `Surveys` collection for each.
2. Since this will issue a new query, you want to avoid loading the `Surveys` collection either lazily or eagerly before this explict load. Otherwise, you're querying the same information twice, which is very inefficient. The easiest way to ensure that is to remove the `virtual` keyword from the collection property. However, if you do that, then you will have to eager or explicitly load the collection or it will be null. For more information, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx